# Find out if current time is start of a new second

Tags: c++, time

I'm writing a progress bar function and want to call it during some task.

```
void someTask() {
    int j = 500000000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        progressBar("Iterating...", i, j);
    }
}
void progressBar(string consoleOut, int current, int end) {
    stringstream progressMessage;
    string status = consoleOut;
    string endOfString = " \r";
    if (current == end) {
        status += " done!";
        endOfString = " \n";
    }
    progressMessage << status;
    for (int i = status.length(); i < 40; i++) {
        progressMessage << " ";
    }
    progressMessage << " [";
    double step = ((double)current / (double)end) * 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < floor(step); i++) {
        progressMessage << "=";
    }
    for (int i = floor(step); i < 10; i++) {
        progressMessage << " ";
    }
    progressMessage << "] " << floor(step*10) << "%";
    cout << progressMessage.str() << endOfString;
}
```

This will give an output like:

```
Iterating...          [          ] 0%
```

Replacing itself and filling up the progress bar as the function continues. I want to display the progress bar at most once a second, though. Instead of:

```
progressBar("Iterating...", i, j);
```

I'd like:

```
if (time(0).milliseconds == 0) {
    progressBar("Iterating...", i, j);
}
```

If time were SS:MS, the function is called if the time is SS:00. So it'll happen at 01:00, 02:00, 03:00, etc. As it is right now, it calls every iteration of `i`, killing performance.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Might want to reconsider your proposed solution: What happens if you go from 999 ms to 1 ms without testing at 0 ms (say, your process got bumped off the CPU by higher priority work).

Comment: That's a good point. I guess I could set a global `time_t timeSeed` var to current time in `main()`, then in my `if` statement, check if `time(0) > timeSeed`, and `timeSeed = time(0)` inside the `progressBar()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply store the current time (using `std::chrono::steady_clock`) at the beginning of the operation, then on each step, check whether the time is at least one second later.  If so, update the progress bar and store the new current time.